# How to carry sublime text 2 settings to linux

Tags: windows-7, sublimetext2, ubuntu-12.04

I want to develop in Linux but all my nice settings are in Windows. How can I carry all the settings and plugins over to my Linux installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy your "Data Directory" to the appropriate place on your destination computer and all your settings and bundles should follow (after a restart). Here is the location of the data directory on each OS:

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2
- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2
- Linux: ~/.Sublime Text 2